# Return no match for literal "Login" but return match for "LoginForm"

Tags: regex

Hello I have the following regex:

```
(?s)\A((?!(?i)Login).)*\Z
```

When tested against 'Hello', I get a match: correct.
When tested against 'Login', I **do not** get a match, correct.
When tested against 'LoginForm', I do not get a match, **incorrect**.

How can the regex be changed to allow the rules above?

thank you

Comment: Do you want any word with "Login" in it?

Comment: @Ben Roux: I would like a match when the word is not Login. (case insensitively)

Comment: So you want everything BUT "Login" and "login"?

Comment: Correct :) (as strange as it sounds)

Comment: Is there a specific need for regex here? This is easier to do with basic string functions if you are doing this in code... or is this for an egrep or sed, etc

Comment: It is used as part of a generic validation system, so there is not much room to move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
(?s)\A(?!^(?i)Login$).*\Z
```

Answer (score -1):

```
/\b(?!Login$)[a-zA-Z]+\b/i
```

Kept playing around with it trying to simplify